# Can I output multiple value in bash, like read A B C <<< "1 2 3"?

Tags: bash

I am learning bash shell.
I found a command "read" which can deliver multiple values to different variables, like

```
read A B C ... <<< "1 2 3 ..."
```

Now I make a function

```
function echo_multiple_values() {
  echo "1 2 3 ..."
}
```

Do I have a smart way to output multiple values from a function, like

```
A B C ...=$(echo_multiple_values)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can't do `A B C ...=$(echo_multiple_values)` imho.

Comment: Thank you sjsam. Thanks to your instruction, I can stop searching the way which does not exist. Maybe another way is read A B C ... <<< $(echo_multiple_values). Thank you again.

Comment: what about `set -- 1 "2 3" 4 ; echo "${#@}->${@}"` ; returns `3->1 2 3 4`. So the `"2 3"` (but without the dbl-quotes) would be in `$2`. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do

```
A B C ...=$(echo_multiple_values)
```

but you may wish to do something like below :

```
myfun(){
arr=( {1..3} ) #{a..b} is a bash range
echo "${arr[@]}"
}

read a b c <<<"$(myfun)"
```

Also, you could do something like below

```
$alphabets=( {a..z} )
$ nums=( {1..26} )
$ read "${alphabets[@]}" <<<"${nums[@]}"
$ echo $a
1
$ echo $c
3
$ echo $z
26
```